# GooglePlay Leaderboards And inAppPurchases

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm implementing in-app purchases and Leaderboards from GooglePlay to my game.
I can easily connect to Google account throughout my app. I see the message "Hello, nickname", GooglePlay icon etc.

1. When I hit "Leaderboards" button I can see leaderboard activity loading. But it won't show totally. I even can enter Leaderboard -> Settings -> And see my account details and log out.
2. On press Remove Ads button I can see an error "DF-RPC-01". After lock->unlock phone sometimes I can see purchase intent. But most of the cases I see this error.

My app is in Closed Beta version with testers added.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1952), if Leaderboard is not working, try adding this code in the Android Manifest.

```
<activity 
android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
/>
```

For the error `DF-RPC-01`, as referred in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/VL1iN_7TODA), you might encounter this if your payment was deactivated. You may also check this [page](https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-fix-the-problem-DF-RPC-01-in-android-lollipop) for additional information.